# Validate Headers ON CSV & TXT

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have a basic import tool that we are using to upload into our database using PHP.
Here is a sample script. 
My question is how can I validate the headers before import? Basically check against a value to make sure the right file is getting imported.I looked everywhere online, but can't seem to find the answer
My headers are

> SKU, Price, Active
>
> > LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE `sample`.`your_temp_table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '    '
> >     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
> >     //Continue to run rest of script

My question is how to validate the headers before the script is ran?
I'm using

> $file = $_GET['file']; 
>   $file = urldecode ($file); //getting file on upload

Comment: Passing `$_GET` values directly into your query is a [super bad idea](http://bobby-tables.com/). Please absolutely certain that's [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I understand. What would you recommend is a better solution?

Comment: Escaping things is a better solution. Even better: Using a database layer like PDO that supports binding to placeholders.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you will need to read the first line of the `$file` and compare it to a set list of headers:

```
$requiredHeaders = array('SKU', 'Price', 'Active'); //headers we expect

$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$firstLine = fgets($f); //get first line of csv file
fclose($f); // close file    

$foundHeaders = str_getcsv(trim($firstLine), ',', '"'); //parse to array

if ($foundHeaders !== $requiredHeaders) {
   echo 'Headers do not match: '.implode(', ', $foundHeaders);
   die();
}

//run import script…
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm not to certain on the $f = fopen($file, 'r'); The rest I can try and I'll let you know.

Comment: It's worth noting that with some more coding you can make the `INSERT` statement adapt to what headers are present.

Comment: As in if you have a mapping table between header `X` and column `x`, then you can identify which headers are present, determine which columns you'll be inserting into, and make an adaptable importer. That way if columns are missing or re-ordered, your `INSERT` will still work.

Comment: I'm not doing a direct insert in this case, I'm using a temp table and than doing update statements as it's actually going to several tables at once.    I have a file, it's actually an Amazon file, that the headers a located 4 rows down. What would be the best way to read that row? Using the Length